# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.core'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My python version is python3.8.8.
I installed tensorflow2.7 on a linux server.
And when I import **tensorflow.keras**. It shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/research/dept8/msc/xcxia21/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/research/dept8/msc/xcxia21/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "/research/dept8/msc/xcxia21/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util.deprecation import deprecated
  File "/research/dept8/msc/xcxia21/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.tools.docs import doc_controls
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tools'
```

I tried to uninstall tensorflow2.7 and install older version tensorflow2.2
the error becomes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_mnist1.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow.keras as keras
  File "/research/dept8/msc/xcxia21/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/research/dept8/msc/xcxia21/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.core'
```

1. I am confused about why I need to import **tensorflow.tools** or **tensorflow.core** when I only want to import **tensorflow.keras**?
2. Someone told me I should build a virtual environment to deal with it. But I would like to know why **tensorflow.tools** and **tensorflow.core** are missing?
3. Besides, when I install tensorflow using pip. The installation always stops(see below). Several minutes later I have to terminate it. Does it cause some packages missing?[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using `pip3` instead just `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.7 requires to install keras individually with `pip install keras` an then you can use keras like before the release: `from tensorflow import keras`.